# Is it possible to have typescript declaration file for a script loaded library?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I am building a library, let's call it `X.js`. It can be loaded via:

1. NPM
2. script tag in an index.html file, and attaches to the window as `window.X` to be called elsewhere in a developer's code.

I have created a declarations (index.d.ts) file for this, and am including it in the NPM module. When testing the npm module locally, the typings work great in VSCode.

My declarations file will also be on DefinitelyTyped (`@types/`). My question is, how does a developer go about getting these typings to help them develop locally if they are loading `X.js` via option 2 above, via script tag?

It seems like this should be possible, but what does an end user of `X.js` have to do to get it to work, and is there anything special I need to do as the developer of `X.js`'s `index.d.ts` file to help?